# How to use symbols as parameters for javascript functions

Tags: javascript, parameters, special-characters

In my header i'm using the function

```
 function changefinal(text)
     {      
         if (text == ".")
           {
               final = final + "."; 
           }
     }
```

But when I call the function as changefinal(.) my final variable does not change. Not sure what I'm  doing wrong here. Am I defining the parameter wrong?

Comment: When and how is `final` defined?

Answer (score 2):

You have to quote your symbols. In JavaScript, a double quotation character has the same effect as a single quote-character. When you're quoting something in JavaScript, the contents inside the quote is interpreted literally, and the created object is a string.

```
changefinal(".");
changefinal('.');
```

If you ever have to use a literal quote inside the same quote (example`"` inside `"..."`), a prefix the inner quote by a backslash, to *escape* the quote:

```
var string = 'I\'m Rob W.';
alert(string); //shows: I'm Rob W.

var attempt = 'I'm Rob W.'; //Notice: No backslash
                 ^ Syntax error
```

Comment: @user782311 This code works. Your problem is located somewhere else.

Comment: ok well im using onclick to call the function <form action="" method="get"><input type="button" value="." onclick=" changefinal('.')" /> would that have something to do with it?

Comment: Your variable `final` is set to `final + "."`. Where are you handling the `final` variable?

Comment: final is declared earlier as var final = "";

Comment: In the global scope (=not in a function?). I meant, how did you know that "It's not working"? You had to check the variable somewhere. How did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
changefinal(.);
```

is a syntax error.  You probably want

```
changefinal(".");
```